# Why is my version of Hy unknown and deftag undefined?

Tags: hy

Why `hy unknown`?

How to use `deftag`?

Snippet from http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/api.html#deftag

```
    gt@gt-ThinkPad-X230:~$ hy --spy
    hy unknown using CPython(default) 3.6.8 on Linux
    => (deftag ♣ [expr] `[~expr ~expr])
    from hy import HyList
    deftag(♣, [expr], HyList((([] + [expr]) + [expr])))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
        exec(code, self.locals)
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'deftag' is not defined
    => (exit)
exit()
```

Comment: The error message suggests that your version of Hy is quite old, but the version number is missing (that's what would be in place of "unknown"). Try using either the latest stable version or the HEAD of GitHub master, and install Hy with one of the recommended methods.

Comment: I've flagged to close this for lack of follow-up.

Comment: I get a version number if I run it in  virtualenv.  I will do that going forward.

Thanks!